# Any good resource for symfony 1.4 twitter/FB/Google oauth integration?

Tags: php, oauth, symfony-1.4

How do I implement Oauth using Symfony 1.4? Any good plugins to use out-of-the box for twitter/FB etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for symfony to consume many providers :
[sfMelodyPlugin](https://github.com/chok/sfMelodyPlugin)